# Installshield without installing required software window first

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I created a setup project that has as required software .NET 4.5. Right now if I don't have installed .net 4.5 the installation will start with installing .net framework first. I would like to avoid this behavior and to receive directly an error message saying that I don't have installed .net version on my computer. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have enabled the .NET 4.5 prerequisite. Prerequisites are designed to check the machine and conditionally install a redistributable before the main installation begins.

The flip side of this is a Launch Condition, at least in a basic MSI project. Use a System Search to detect whether .NET 4.5 is present (feel free to edit the .NET 4.5 prerequisite to get an idea what to look for, or just research it yourself), and add a Launch Condition with the message you want to show.

It's actually a really good idea to set up the Launch Condition even if you are including the prerequisite, just in case someone launches the .msi file without going through setup.exe's prerequisite checks. And for your case, where you don't want to offer the automatic installation, just stop including the prerequisite.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to create a new launch condition (option file path - as specified by a registry entry), but it still ask me to install .NET 4.5 first before. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @vladcristea: Did you remove (uncheck) the .NET 4.5 prerequsite?

Comment: Yes, I removed it, and I set a specific error message for my launch condition, and when it asks me if I want to install .net framework and I press cancel, I get my specific error message.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your response. You were right. I had to uncheck in prerequisites. Thank you very much :)